# How to check the hashrate per GPU running Ubuntu nvOC

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia

Running nvOC with 9 1070 GTX GPUs. First time I set it up the hash-rate was 270 (Mining Eth) which make sence, however, it dropped to 240.

All the GPUs still running, I am new to this and I was wondering if there is a way where I can check individual GPU hash rate (So the hash rate per GPU) so that I can diagnose what is wrong.